# Change text of TextBoxFor on change of select tag

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, html.textboxfor

Here is my code.

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Branch)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @{ Booking_Program.Models.Booking_DB_Entities db = new Booking_Program.Models.Booking_DB_Entities();
           <select onchange="onChangeBranch()" id="branchStr">
           @for (int i = 0; i <= 3;i++ )
           {
            <option id="@i" value="@i.ToString()">@i.ToString()</option>
           }
        </select>
        }
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Branch, new { id = "branch" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Branch)
    </div>
```

And javascript is as below.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function onChangeBranch() {
           var brnch = document.getElementById("branchStr").value;
           alert(brnch);
          $("#branch").val(brnch).change();
     }  
 </script>
```

what is wrong with this code? i get `alert`, but this does not change the value of `TextboxFor`. How to do it?

Comment: Does changing `$("#branch").val(brnch).change();` to `$("#branch").val(brnch);` help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's the purpose of `.change()` at the the end of this line

```
$("#branch").val(brnch).change();
```

Setting a field value with JQuery is done like this

```
$("#branch").val(brnch);
```

or

```
$("#branch")[0].value = brnch;
```

Comment: Even that does not help

Comment: That helped a lot. Well what I did is `<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#branchStr').change(function () {
        $('#branch').val(this.value);
    });
</script>`

Comment: Glad it helped :) That's the way I would normally use it.